# Overriding browser scrolling behavior?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have an user interface idea that requires overriding the browser's scroll functionality so I can create my own behaviors for the scroll action.

Is there a way to prevent the window from scrolling when the user scrolls?

Comment: Do you want to replace main scrollbar action?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in using the scroll action (scroll wheel, arrows, etc) to enable other functionality on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
​$(window).scroll(function() {
   $(this).scrollTop(0);
});​​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6RLnp/)

Comment: Add `$(this).scrollLeft(0);` too I suppose if you want to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [jQuery Scrollbar](http://naeka.github.com/jquery-scrollbar/) library which requires:

1. jQuery (version 1.6+)
2. jQuery UI Widget (for Widget Factory)

You can download the library here: https://github.com/Naeka/jquery-scrollbar. Here's a [demo](http://naeka.github.com/jquery-scrollbar/).

Here are options for the scrollbar:

```
$("#scroll").scrollbar({
    classes: '',         // Extra classes for css styling
    wheel: 40,           // Scroll offset on mousewheel
    scroll: true,        // Allow / disallow mouse scrolling
    overlay: true,       // Scrollbars are overlaid
    autohide: true,      // Scrollbars are automatically hidden
    animate: {           // Scroll wheel animation - set to false to disable
        duration: 300,
        easing: 'swing'
    }
});
```

And you can scroll to certain ID in the page on specific events:

```
$("#scroll").scrollbar("scrollTo", "#p");
```

Here are more options for scrollTo usage:

```
scrollTo([offsetX, offsetY])
scrollTo(selector)
scrollTo(jQuery object)
```