# How to create animation based on scroll like this website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently come across this website

http://estimote.com/

First you may notice at the end of this website there is a man standing at the room door . You may search keywords "What are the practical applications?" to locate that place.

There is a effect that , when the user scroll the mouse , the screen has some reaction base on the scroll , say , in this website, the man will walk in the room , if user scroll downside , on the other hand, if user scroll another side then , the man leave the room.

It seems the effect is just scroll then change image url? I would like to make the question more specific , how to override the scroll event, and execute some function ?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link - > [Override Scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800622/overriding-browser-scrolling-behavior)

Comment: Skrollr is a very good framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the developertools you can see that they are changing the images, as you mentioned.
You could recreate this with jQuery, use something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function()
  {
    var aTop = $('#animationContainer').height();
    var framesShown = 0;
    var framesTotal = 10;

    if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop){
        if(framesShown != framesTotal)
        {
            e.preventDefault()
            showNextFrame(framesShown + 1);
            framesShown++;
        } 
    }
  });
});
```

*This code is not intended to be functional*